# Restrict sorting to a certain range

Tags: matrix, associations, sorting

**Example data** (revised to include negative values - see comment of @ydd)

```
data =
  <|"France" -> <|"18" -> -103.7`, "19" -> -103.9`, "20" -> -104.1`, 
     "21" -> -104.6`, "22" -> -105.`|>, 
   "Greece" -> <|"18" -> 96.6`, "19" -> 96.5`, "20" -> 96.4`, 
     "21" -> 96.`, "22" -> 94.1`|>, 
   "Italy" -> <|"18" -> -102.2`, "19" -> -101.1`, "20" -> -100.8`, 
     "21" -> -100.1`, "22" -> -99.7`|>, 
   "Portugal" -> <|"18" -> 97.3`, "19" -> 97.2`, "20" -> 97.4`, 
     "21" -> 97.4`, "22" -> 97.9`|>, 
   "Spain" -> <|"18" -> 100.4`, "19" -> 101.`, "20" -> 101.8`, 
     "21" -> 102.`, "22" -> 102.`|>, 
   "Total" -> <|"18" -> 88.4`, "19" -> 89.7`, "20" -> 90.7`, 
     "21" -> 90.7`, "22" -> 89.3`|>|>;

data // Dataset
```

[image]

I sometimes import data tables with column totals already appended. If I want to `ReverseSort` this data by the last column, the total row must of course stay in place. Therefore:

```
sorted = <|ReverseSortBy[Last] @ data[[;; -2]], KeyTake[Last @ Keys @ data] @ data|>;

sorted // Dataset
```

[image]

Although I can live with this not too complicated solution, I'm curious to know if there isn't a more direct approach, which wouldn't deconstruct and reassemble the matrix.

Comment: [`SubsetMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, [`SubsetMap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap.html) appears to be perfect for the task. However, since it explicitly acts on a `List` of the elements (values) of the subset, keys remain in their original places:

```
SubsetMap[ReverseSortBy[Last]@*Echo, data, ;; -2] // Dataset
```

[image: A sorted dataset... except the labels haven't moved]

To work around this, we can `Normal`ize the initial association into a list of `key->value` rules, then apply `Association` to the result. This also changes what `ReverseSortBy` sees, so we compose with `Last` to work on values again:

```
SubsetMap[ReverseSortBy[Last@*Last], Normal@data, ;; -2] // 
  Association // Dataset
```

[image: A properly sorted dataset]

Comment: I get exactly the same result with `ReverseSortBy[Last]` (omitting the composed `@*Last`

Comment: @eldo that's because in this case, the rows (and all columns) sort the same as the last column.

Answer (score 6):

You just need to ReverseSort the data and shift the total to the bottom:

```
RotateLeft[ReverseSortBy[data, Last], 1] // Dataset
```

[image]

---

**add-on**

Since I rely on `"Total"` being the largest (first in `RevereSortBy`) row, this is only guaranteed to work for positive values in `data`

---

For negative values, I can't really think of a better way yet to do it than yours. I think your method is quite clear and good already. But this is my attempt:

```
sorted = Join[ReverseSort@Most@data, Part[data, {-1}]];
sorted // Dataset
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly, I should have included negative values - will revise the question - +1 anyway

Comment: Ok, I added a method for negative values. I'm worried it doesn't really add much though to the method you've already got in your question

Answer (score 3):

```
rsort = Apply[Association] @* Through @* 
  {ReverseSortBy[{Key @ "22"}] @* KeyDrop["Total"], KeyTake["Total"]};


Dataset @ rsort @ data
```

[image]

```
Query[rsort] @ Dataset @ data
```

[image]

```
data2 = data;
data2["France", "18"] = 102.0;
Dataset @ rsort @ data2
```

[image]

Comment: Extremely nice! But it would give a wrong result if , for example, we would change the value for `France` in column `18` from `-103.7` to `102.0`. See comments following `@att`s solution.

Comment: This is of course my mistake, not yours, because I should have included this possibility in the example data.

Comment: @eldo, please try the updated version.,

Comment: Now it's perfect :)

Answer (score 3):

One approach, calling [`ReverseSort`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReverseSort.html) only on the relevant data:

```
(ReverseSort@Most@Query[All,"22"]@data//Keys//Append["Total"]//Query)@data//Dataset
```

[image]

**Original Answer**

```
Query[ReverseSort[Query[;;-2,-1]@data]//Keys//Append["Total"]]@data
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way to go! Can be shortened to `Query[ReverseSort[data[[;; -2]]] // Keys // Append["Total"]]@data // Dataset`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?:

```
data = <|"France" -> <|"18" -> 103.7, "19" -> 103.9, "20" -> 104.1, 
     "21" -> 104.6, "22" -> 105.2|>, 
   "Greece" -> <|"18" -> 96.6, "19" -> 96.5, "20" -> 96.4, 
     "21" -> 96.0, "22" -> 94.1|>, 
   "Italy" -> <|"18" -> 102.2, "19" -> 101.1, "20" -> 100.8, 
     "21" -> 100.1, "22" -> 99.7|>, 
   "Portugal" -> <|"18" -> 97.3, "19" -> 97.2, "20" -> 97.4, 
     "21" -> 97.4, "22" -> 97.9|>, 
   "Spain" -> <|"18" -> 100.4, "19" -> 101.5, "20" -> 101.8, 
     "21" -> 102.0, "22" -> 102.1|>, 
   "Total" -> <|"18" -> 500.2, "19" -> 499.7, "20" -> 500.5, 
     "21" -> 500.1, "22" -> 498.7|>|>;
data = Transpose@ReverseSortBy[Transpose@data, Last];
data // Dataset
```

[image]

Comment: No, the table should be reverse sorted by the last column, not by the last row. Exactly like the second table in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Following the comment of `@att` I tried it with `SubsetMap`:

```
SubsetMap[ReverseSortBy[Last], data, 1 ;; -2] // Dataset
```

[image]

This sorted the `Values` as desired but not the `Keys`.

To also sort the `Keys` we must transform `data` into a `List` of `Association`s with this little helper function:

```
keysup = KeyValueMap[<|"" -> #1, #2|> &] @ # &;
```

To return to an `Association` of `Association`s we need:

```
keysdown = GroupBy[#, First -> Rest, Last] &;
```

Now, finally, the wanted result:

```
SubsetMap[ReverseSortBy[Last], keysup[data], 1 ;; -2] // keysdown // Dataset
```

[image]

Hmm, this restricted the sort range, but at what expense!

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the issue with the keys. Might be more elegant to have `keysup=Association`, `keysdown=Normal`, and `ReverseSortBy[Last@*Last]` instead.

Comment: If you would write this as an answer, I would certainly accept it :)